# How can I get address suggestion under search box and not under search box label?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, dynamics-365, pcf

[What I Get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojcEs.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9gzB.png)

hello everyone,
I am working on PCF control. In which I am getting UI as shown in 1st but I want it as it is shown in second image.
I want the address suggestion under the search box not under the search box label.
how can I fix this?

here is my code:.css file

```
.control {
background: transparent;
border-style: none;
/* font-size: 1rem; */
/* font-weight: 600; */
height: 35px;
line-height: 35px;
width: 90%;
padding-left: 0em;
padding-right: 0em;
padding-top: 0em;
padding-bottom: 0em;
outline: 0 !important;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
text-indent: 1px;
text-overflow: '';
```

}

.ts file

```
this.searchBoxLabel = document.createElement("label");
    this.searchBoxLabel.textContent = "Enter Address";
    this.searchBoxLabel.className = "label control";
    this.searchBoxLabelDiv = document.createElement("div");
    this.searchBoxLabelDiv.className = "labelDiv";
    this.searchBoxLabelDiv.appendChild(this.searchBoxLabel);

    //this.notifyOutputChanged = notifyOutputChanged;
    this.searchBox = document.createElement("input");
    this.searchBox.setAttribute("id", "searchBox-"+ this.uniqueId);
    this.searchBox.setAttribute("type", "search");
    this.searchBox.className = "text control";
    this.searchBox.setAttribute("placeholder", "For eg: 101 victoria park");
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to provide code sample so that others can help you resolve the problem.

Comment: I have updated my question, can you please check it now?